# Create Artifact In Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I created a Jenkins item which is not freestyle, so I don't have the option to run post build action in manage. I try to force the pipeline generate a summary.html file keep the report of whenever it is built. However, I could not find that file. Here is my code from the example repository [enter link description here](https://github.com/thanhdatnasdaq/Data-Request)

```
def call(projectName, requiredAgent='java8'){
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage("Build Stage"){
            steps{
                echo "Enter build stage"
                sh "pwd"
                sh "whoami"
                sh "env"
            }
        }
        stage("Test Stage"){
            steps{
                echo "Enter test stage"
            }
        }
        stage("Deploy Stage"){
            steps{
                echo "Enter deploy stage"
            }
        }
    }
    post{
            always{
                publishHTML( [reportName: 'Summary',
                                  allowMissing: true,
                                  alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                                  keepAll: true,
                                  reportDir: '',
                                  reportFiles: 'summary.html',
                                  reportTitles: 'Build Summary'] )
            }
        } 
}
}
```